# XDocReport converting odt to pdf how to set proper locale

Tags: pdf, localization, freemarker, odt, xdocreport

I'm trying to convert some `*.odt` file to `*.pdf` using [IXDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki).

Here is the hypothetical content of the `*.odt` file: `${amount?string.currency} to be paid`

Here is the code I do conversion with (you can run it in kotlin REPL):

```
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterTypeTo
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterTypeVia
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.Options
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.IXDocReport
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.TemplateEngineKind
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.File

val options: Options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.ODFDOM)
val content: ByteArray = File("/home/sandro/tmp/report.odt").readBytes()
val templateId: String = "someId"
val registry: XDocReportRegistry = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry()
val data: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf("amount" to 10)

ByteArrayInputStream(content).use { input ->
    val report: IXDocReport =
        registry.loadReport(input, templateId, TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker, true)
    val tmpFile: File = createTempFile("out", ".pdf")

    tmpFile.outputStream().use { output ->
        report.convert(data, options, output)

        println(tmpFile.toString())
    }
}
```

and the result is the pdf file with string `$10.00 to be paid`

How can I set needed locale to XDocReport during conversion so the result could be changed to other currencies correctly?

**P.S.** I cannot control the template itself - so please do not tell me to add `<#setting locale="${bean.locale}">` or something else to the template itself. The only place I can change is the code. Thanks in advance.

**P.P.S.** I need to render many templates per request and need to set locale per each template.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used XDocReport, but maybe this will work: https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/FreemarkerTemplate "How to configure Freemarker?"

Quotation from there:

> To configure Freemarker with XDocReport you must get the Configuration instance. To do > that you must
>
> 1. create a class (ex :
>      fr.opensagres.xdocreport.MyFreemarkerConfiguration) which implements
>      fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.discovery.ITemplateEngineInitializerDiscovery.
> 2. register with SPI this class by creating the file
>      META-INF/services/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.discovery.ITemplateEngineInitializerDiscovery
>      with the name of you class :
>      fr.opensagres.xdocreport.MyFreemarkerConfiguration This file should be
>      in your classpath (you can for instance host it in the
>      src/META-INF/services/ of your project).

So you will need a class like this:

```
public class MyFreemarkerConfiguration implements ITemplateEngineInitializerDiscovery {

    [...]

    public void initialize(ITemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        if (TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker.name().equals( templateEngine.getKind())) {
            Configuration cfg = ((FreemarkerTemplateEngine) templateEngine).getFreemarkerConfiguration();
            cfg.setLocale(...);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one look good, I'll take a look. But how could I change locale per request?

Comment: While FreeMarker supports per-request locale (both as `Configuration.getTemplate` parameter, and by setting the locale in the `Environment` of the template processing), I don't know if XDocReport provides any hook. If not, then maybe you can introduce some hack via an auto-include you set in the `Configuration`, and then in the auto-included template call a Java utility that picks up the desired locale (from thread-local or such), and sets it in the current `Environment` (which you can get via `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment()`). Based on what should you decide the request locale anyway?

Comment: It comes from the application that uses my library through the method parameter, and for the very same instance there could be a lot of different locales, based on request.

Comment: Can you put variables into the data-model for each request? Then you can put the desired settings there into a Map, and the pick it up in an auto-included template and apply them on the `Envionment`. If you don't control the data-model, thread locals may still work for the same purpose. Of course, the cleanest would be if XDocReport allows you to specify something that sets up the `Environment` before the template is processed... But auto-include is the workaround if they don't.